# Edit/Update Current User Information MVC ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I need to create an action which allows me to update some fields for the current user.

i did come across Membership.GetUser but i can't figure out how to use it.

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AccountInfo([Bind(Include = "UserName, Address, Region, Email, Phone")]UserProfile UserProfile)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {  

            }

        }
```

Am not sure how to code this part.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.net membership,then code like below :

```
MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
u.Email = someValue;
Membership.UpdateUser(u);
```